# 2000AD prose and pictures story. Female protagonist looking for someone called Doom

Tags: story-identification, 2000ad

I'm trying to recall a 2000AD (prose and pictures?) story featuring a female protagonist who, I think, normally appeared in comic form. In the story she was trying to locate someone named Brigand Doom. I think he might have been attacking people in their dreams(?).

The story started off with a line that went something like...

> *"His name was actually just Doom. Brigand was something that I called him"*

... and ended with the woman sitting up in bed wearing a white t-shirt, possibly slightly silhouetted.

I'm reasonably sure I read this in a 2000AD that was after prog #1000.

Comment: Note that there was a 2000AD story called [Brigand Doom](https://britishcomics.fandom.com/wiki/Brigand_Doom). Not the same guy